# Angularjs - Passwords/Security Questions transmitted over query string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, security, templates

I am using Angularjs as my front-end framework for the app I am currently working on. I am having a problem with the partial HTML when testing security.

File: /modals/login.html - contains HTML form with email and password

When testing I get this URL: http://localhost:8080/templates/modal/login.html?ddce4e244a538a4f=3&email=fakeemail%40example.com&password=fakepassword but from the application itself, User credentials are never transferred in this way.

How to prevent this from being flagged as the issue?

Comment: Do you mean because the email and password are visible in the URL? You need to POST (not GET) the form.

Comment: Yes. My form doesn't have method attribute but form is prevented and handled in a different way. You are telling just to add method="POST" to my form tag? @ShaunWebb

Comment: What code do you have currently?

Comment: @ShaunWebb this is my login.html file https://pastebin.com/c2pHMNnw